# How to save .csv paths in a object?

Tags: powershell

I have a `foreach` loop that works like that:
I load an object from XML, so an object composed from city and email of the ICT Head, then I set the future export path using the email. I also set `$CurrentCity` to get the city we are cycling on.
Then I make a query and check in a full report if there is that city taken from the object we are cycling in, and if there is, I make an export with the corresponding path (as I said before including corresponding email address).

The problem is that I'm gonna send those mail next but I need to collect path of the attachment and email of the recipient in an object.
How can I do that? I thought I could make a simple object AttachmentPath and Email and then make a foreach into that to get every time the values and send the mail who will be with single-attachment.

```
$LCL_Setting.Local_Config.LF_param.IctHead.city | foreach {
    $tempfile = $myDir + $dir_out + $fileOut + $LogDate +'_'+$_.ICT_mail +'.csv'
    $CurrentCity = $_.Branch

    if ($result | where {$_.City -eq "$($CurrentCity)"}) {
        $result |
            where {$_.City -eq "$($CurrentCity)"} |
            Export-Csv $tempfile -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `$result`?`

Comment: @Tomalak a report object structured like this Username City Error, so I check if the city I wrote on the XML are the same of the $result and make a report for any city.

Comment: Tip 1: You can use the `Select-Xml` cmdlet and XPath to directly select the matching parts of the XML. Tip 2: Why write a second `foreach` loop when you could send the email directly in the current one? You would not need any temporary variables in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build custom objects with the e-mail address and output file path like this:

```
$temp_files = $LCL_Setting.Local_Config.LF_param.IctHead.city | foreach {
    ...
    if ($result | where {$_.City -eq "$($CurrentCity)"}) {
        ...
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            'Mail' = $_.ICT_mail
            'File' = $tempfile
        }
    }
}
```

However, using a hashtable instead of a list of custom objects might be a better approach, because it allows you to look up the file path by e-mail address.

```
$temp_files = @{}
$LCL_Setting.Local_Config.LF_param.IctHead.city | foreach {
    ...
    if ($result | where {$_.City -eq "$($CurrentCity)"}) {
        ...
        $temp_files[$_.ICT_mail] = $tempfile
    }
}
```